# How is the difference between these two momentjs dates 0?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a function that is looking to determine if a date is in the past. It uses moment to take the difference between these two dates. However when the given date is tomorrow the difference is 0 when I'd expect for it to be 1.

```
const isPastDate = (date) => {
  if (date) {
    console.log(date);

    const givenDate = moment(date);
    const today = moment();

    console.log("givenDate => ", givenDate);
    console.log("today => ", today);
    const diff = today.diff(givenDate, "days");

    console.log("diff => ", diff);
    const result = diff >= 0;
    return result;
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: you're asking for the difference in `days` but the dates are less than a day apart (by 11 mins and 48 seconds) so the diff is 0 days.

Comment: If you want to know if a date is before another date why not use [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)? You can also use the third parameter to get a float instead of having it rounded.

Comment: @DaveNewton i had no idea that existed. Thank you!